# What applications use Java on a desktop?

Tags: java

I get the "There's a update for Java" notification on my computer. And as its a security update, I feel like I should get the new update and each time, I need to go through an installation process and stuff and it gets tedious?

I was wondering, what software typically uses Java on a desktop? Is it just those java applets? Cause hardly any websites have them these days. Do I need these updates? Do I need Java at all? Should I just uninstall Java?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should, most certainly, install the security updates for the java virtual machine. This will, even if you don't use many Java applications, keep your computer safer from all the different vulnerabilities that are covered by the different security patches.

As for software that runs using the Java Virtual Machine (JVM), typical programs might be:

Eclipse (Open Source IDE for Programming)

Azureus(BitTorrent Client)

OpenOffice

LibreOffice

NetBeans IDE (Another Programming IDE)

LimeWire

Vuze

MATLAB (Advanced Mathematics Programming)

Lotus Notes (E-mail/Productivity Suite)

Comment: uTorrent doesn't use Java!

Comment: Sorry, my bad, it's Azureus which does. I'll correct that.

Comment: Azureus and Vuse are the same program.

Comment: Just like to point out that despite common misconceptions, {Libre,Open}Office is actually mostly written in C++; only certain features (particularly Base) require Java.

Comment: thanks, although looking at that list, i only have openoffice, which i barely use (only for reading OO files i need to) so I'll probably uninstall java from my computer

Comment: You're going to need Java for way more than you think. Especially since a huge number of websites use java applets. Java is like .NET Framework; it's something you may not use often, but it's a pain in the rear end if you don't have it. Personally, I'd recommend simply updating it and letting it sit there.

Answer (score 2):

A lot of applications may use Java, java applets too. The upgrade will involve only the JVM (Java Virtual Machine) and not the application using it. It's not tedious, you should do it specially if it is for security reasons.

> Do I need these updates?

Yes, if you have at least one Java application you need it.

> Do I need Java at all?

Probably you need it, depends on the application you have installed. But it is required for a lot of things. I think that still now is the language more used over the world.

> Should I just uninstall Java?

If you are sure that none of your application is using the JVM you could unistall it. I discourage you to do that. It's very probable that you need it now, or in the future.